# REST and JSON for transaction data - iPad

Tags: ios, json, rest, ipad

I am searching for a good solution to manage data updates through REST and JSON.

The client is an iPad and I want that client staying up2date.

The problem is, that the amount of data is very large and may be changed often.

Lets assume I have customer data in the backend. The client iPad should synch this data with the backend system. But customer data may be changed or deleted at any time. Further the amount of customers is >1000. 
I do not really want the client to connect to http://www.example.com/customers/ causing to send a request for each of the 1000 customers in that list...

Any ideas to solve such a problem nicely?